# Implementation of derivative of first Jacobi theta function

Tags: special-functions, computational-mathematics, elliptic-functions

I'm looking for an efficient implementation of the derivative of the first Jacobi theta function $\theta_1(z, \tau)$ or the derivative of its logarithm, which works with complex values of the variable and of the parameter. I implemented the algorithm given in [Beebe's book](https://books.google.be/books?id=OjUyDwAAQBAJ&dq=weierstrass%20carlson&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s) for the derivative of the logarithm; it often works but there is a $\sin(2nz)$ which can becomes huge for $z$ complex, and then the algorithm fails in these cases.